# White Screen Shows for Minutes Before Launching App - Xcode 13 on iOS 15.1.1

Tags: ios, xcode, ios15, xcode13

This is a weird bug I'm getting using Xcode 13 and iOS 15.1.1. I've developed a simple app and when I run the app on iOS 15.1.1 (iPhone 13 Pro), before the app launches a white screen (black in case dark mode is ON), is shown, for couple of minutes.

Does anyone know a work around this? This completely disrupts the development process and breaks the flow while testing the app. Build time is within a minute and you have to wait extra time for the white screen to go away.

I've tried the following solutions but it didn't work

1. Removing **iOS DeviceSupport** and restarting Xcode

`rm -r ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS\ DeviceSupport`

---

**Edit 1: This is happening only when run button from Xcode is pressed and after it once launches from Xcode and then I close the app and start again from phone it works normal**

Deleting DerivedData too did not work

Some code to give reference:

AppDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

@main
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    // MARK: - didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
                   
        let storyboard =  UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        self.window?.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        
        FirebaseApp.configure()
        
        return true
    }

    // MARK: -
    
    // MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
        // Called when a new scene session is being created.
        // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
        return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
    }

    // MARK: - didDiscardSceneSessions
    
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
        // Called when the user discards a scene session.
        // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
        // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
    }

    

}
```

Root VC:

```
import UIKit

class VC_AppleSignIn: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        print("Hello World!")
    }

}
```

[image]

Please let me know if any other code is required!

Comment: Share some code. Did you test your project on a lower iOS version?

Comment: I suggest you try deleting DerivedData and make a clean build. Also some code sharing would help

Comment: If you don't give more information, no one can help you and you're just throwing away 50 points of rep. Try to understand: nobody else is seeing this problem. So you have to _help us see it_ if you want us to help _you_. It sounds like perhaps you are doing a lot of work on the main thread during launch, which is always wrong behavior. Use Instruments to find out what's happening.

Comment: I will edit the question to add the code, since I create a fresh project with nothing in it and it is working absolutely fine. So the bug's in my code I guess. I'll update the question

Comment: There is a similar problem here but none of their solution is working: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69576384/xcode-debug-on-ios15-blank-white-screen-and-minutes-delay-before-app-starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue finally resolved. I updated my Xcode to 13.2 and it fixed it. Not sure what was causing it. But it's fixed with the new Xcode update